# Model gives great training and testing accuracy but not working well when doing prediction

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Hi there I am doing transfer learning with deep learning using VGG16 pre-trained model. I want to extract features from VGG16 to build my own model as I only have access to CPU. Here is my build and train setup.

```
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

from keras.applications import Xception, VGG16, ResNet50
conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

conv_base.summary()
base_dir = 'NewDCDatatset'

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Validation')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Test')

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
batch_size = 5

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7 , 7 , 512))
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count,2))
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,target_size=(224, 224),batch_size=batch_size,class_mode='categorical')
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size : (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels

train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 2000)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(validation_dir,420 )
test_features, test_labels = extract_features(test_dir, 420)

train_features = np.reshape(train_features, (2000, 7 * 7 * 512))
validation_features = np.reshape(validation_features, (420, 7 * 7 * 512))
test_features = np.reshape(test_features, (420, 7 * 7 * 512))

from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=7 * 7 * 512))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
history = model.fit(train_features, train_labels,epochs=2,batch_size=5,shuffle=True)
print(model.evaluate(test_features,test_labels))

model.save('TLFACE.h5')

#predictions = model.predict_generator(test_features,steps = 5)

#print(predictions)
```

And here is the setup for the way I am predicting the new images through my model to classify cat and dog but I am not getting that much accurate results that seldom I am able to correctly classify any image. I don't what mistake I am doing, is it matter of resizing image or what when predicting.

```
from keras.models import load_model
deep = load_model('TLFACE.h5')

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

file_nam = '4705.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(file_nam)
img = cv2.imshow('frame',img)
cv2.waitKey(1000)

img = Image.open(file_nam).convert("L")

img = img.resize((256,98))
im2arr = np.array(img)
im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,25088)
# Predicting the Test set r1esults
y_pred = deep.predict(im2arr)
print(y_pred)
print(y_pred[0][0])
```

Comment: Well without looking at your code, the issue you explain can sometimes be solved by limiting the network size, forcing it to generalize. How much percentage of the data are you training with and how much do you test with?

Comment: I have 4000 train images (2000 images per class) and 420 test images (210 per class).

Comment: So it performs well on those 4000 and 420 images then? What is the difference from the test images and the "new images"?

Comment: Yes Em getting 92% training accuracy and 90% testing accuracy when when evaluating the model on test dateset. But when I am predicting it on new images (that are different or even from the test images folder), it is not giving good results.

Comment: Okay, so it seems your test data is not actually test data but training data somehow. The idea of the test data is that they should not affect the network(s) in any way, i.e. the test data should be isolated. There should be no difference from the test data and the "new images" as you call them. See this article on cross validation: https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, your model receives a feature vector of size `1 x 7*7*512 = 1 x 25088`. This features is the encoding of an image in the `conv_base` model (implemented in your `extract_features` method).

However in your example at prediction time you just take an image, reshape it to `(256,98)`, then flatten to `(1,25088)`. You totally skip the `extract_features` phase. In other words, you try to predict on a totally different data then you use during training (and the automated testing under the `fit` method). You need to use the exact same preprocessing method for testing, which means first rescale the image to size `224x224x3`, then extracting the features using the `conv_base` model, and finally use your new model to perform the prediction over the extracted features.

Having said that, I want to suggest that you use very "dirty" implementation, this is not organized properly and it easy to get confused that way. You actually want to build a single model that perform classification on an image, and not do all the heavy coding of extracting features etc. to do so you can just use something like:

```py
pretrained_vgg16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
pretrained_vgg16.trainable = False  # This is important if you don't want to modify your base model weights during training.
new_model = models.Sequential([pretrained_vgg16, 
                               layers.Flatten(),
                               layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                               layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax')])
```

In addition, please note that it is very importnat to decide if you want to modify the pre-trained model weights during training or not. if not, you need to envoke the `pretrained_vgg16.trainable = False` line.

Now you can use `new_model.fit` with a generator that load the images and rescale them to `224x224x3`, without explicitly extracting the features. Another important comment is that the original VGG16 model was probably trained on a normalized data (which means pixels values were normalized to be in range `[0,1]`), you also need to perform the same preprocessing to your images for ideal results.